# Remote Simulator to Windows option doesn't exist

Tags: windows

How can get Remote Simulator to Windows when it doesn't exist?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no iOS simulator for Windows.

Xamarin needs you to connect to a Mac capable of running it.

From [Introduction to Xamarin.iOS for Visual Studio](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/introduction_to_xamarin_ios_for_visual_studio/)

> Xamarin for Windows allows iOS applications to be written and tested
>   within Visual Studio, with a networked Mac providing the build and
>   deployment service.
>
> There are a number of configuration options available, so you can
>   decide which works best for your development needs. These are listed
>   below:
>
> - Use a Mac as your main development Machine and run a Windows Virtual
>     Machine with Visual Studio installed. We recommend using VM software
>     such as [Parallels](http://www.parallels.com/products/desktop/) or [VMWare](http://www.vmware.com/products/fusion/) .
> - Use a Mac just as a Build Host. In this
>     scenario it would be simply connected to the same network as a Windows
>     machine with the [necessary](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/#Configuring_The_Mac) tools installed.
>
> In either case, you should
>   follow these steps:
>
> - [Install the Xamarin.iOS tools on your Mac host and activate your license](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/mac/)
> - [Configure your Mac](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/#Configuring_The_Mac)
> - [Install Xamarin tools on Windows](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/#Windows_Installation)
>
> To develop
>   with Xamarin in Visual Studio, you must be using at least Visual
>   Studio 2012 Professional or higher. Xamarin will not work with Express
>   Editions of Visual Studio, as they do not support add-ins.

Comment: i had connect VMware runing os x complete but simulator not working it wasn't exsit in ios setting. How can get it  ? if simulator ios not work how can build app on ios

Answer (score 0):

You need the enterprise license

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/windows/ios-simulator/

> Remoted iOS Simulator requires a Visual Studio Enterprise license